# Search in procedure Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search data from database(Oracle) by using procedure.

My procedure is:

```
PROCEDURE CUSTOMER_SEARCH(
v_customerName VARCHAR2,
v_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN v_Result FOR
SELECT * FROM CHAT_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMERNAME like '%'+v_customername+'%';
END CUSTOMER_SEARCH;
```

But when I test this procedure by input v_customerName = 'a', it shows error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Is there any suggestion to correct my procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: use the correct concatenation characters! In Oracle, `+` is for addition of two numbers, whereas `||` is used to concatenate two strings together. So, your procedure should be:

```
PROCEDURE CUSTOMER_SEARCH(
    v_customerName VARCHAR2,
    v_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN v_Result FOR
  SELECT * FROM CHAT_CUSTOMER
  WHERE CUSTOMERNAME like '%'||v_customername||'%';
END CUSTOMER_SEARCH;
/
```

Bear in mind that you may wish to make both `CUSTOMERNAME` and `v_customername` uppercase by using the `UPPER()` function in order to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you!